# Minimum kernel version for amd64

Tags: linux-kernel, history

Which was the first linux-kernel version available for `amd64` architectures? (also called `x84-64`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [kernel modutils readme](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/modutils/v2.4/README) file, amd64 support was added in 2.4.26, while some comments about [problems](https://vuldb.com/?id.21071) indicate the kernel added support before 2.4.22.

OP noticed that the earliest note for amd64 was for 2.4.15, also in modutils readme:

```
modutils-2.4.15.tar.gz      Expand small snprintf buffers to PATH_MAX.  Add
                            alias ppp-compress-18 ppp_mppe.  Add x86-64
                            support.  Clean up and document modinfo printing
                            of parameters.  Update config.{guess,sub} to
                            2002-03-04.
```

The changelog for 2.4.15 has a file timestamp for November 23, 2001 (see [archive](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.4/)).  Presumably the comment about `config.{guess,sub}` was added *"later"*, as part of preparing the tar ball.

If you look for additional information about 64-bit support in Linux, you will find that there were other changes (such as for ia64, sparc64) which came earlier in the 2.4.x development, and that the date on which a given platform was *"complete"* is somewhat nebulous.  The *Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS 3 Release Notes (AMD64 Edition)* [in 2003](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Release_Notes/as-amd64/index.html) refer to several of these in-progress/incomplete changes.

Comment: That is consistent with a comment that it was added in 2001 (see dates on [2.4 kernel archive](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.4/)).